# How can I write a regular expression that starts with a particular word match and continues until it hits a period

Tags: regex

I trying to write a regular expression that would match a particular word and continue matching until a period is encountered. For example:

Text:

> Which Have Never Won Two Races Other Than Maiden, Claiming, Or Starter Or Which Have Never Won Three Races Or Optional Claiming Price Of $25,000. Three Year Olds, 118 Lbs.; Older, 123 Lbs. Non-winners of $24,000 since March 9 Allowed 2 Lbs.

Desired Match:

> Which Have Never Won Two Races Other Than Maiden, Claiming, Or Starter Or Which Have Never Won Three Races Or Optional Claiming Price Of $25,000.

Regular Expression:

```
(?<Match1>Which\s[a-zA-Z]*[.])
```

Unfortunately my proposed expression captures all of the text and seems to extend to the last period instead of the first.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually pretty simple. Use `[^.]*` to match all characters up  but not including to the next `.` and surround your desired word by `\b` boundaries. I appended the final `.` as `\.` assuming you want to include that in the matched output.

```
(?<Match1>\bWhich\b[^.]*\.)
```

Answer (score 2):

`(?<Match1>Which[^.]*?[.])`

non-greedy match of anything but a period up to a period.

Answer (score 2):

Simple enough:

```
([^.]*This[^.]*\.)
```

See it in action:
http://regexr.com?32b8b

Simply Replace "This" with your word, and you should match all "sentences" (which if you are really looking to do, you should consider adding "!" and "?" to your period in order to match sentences ending in those, too).

edit: This matches the entire sentence if the word is in it at all, if you want only from the word-forward, ie if the word is in the middle of the sentence, then omit the first [^.]* and it should work.

```
(This[^.]*\.)
```